# oracle cursor concurrency with insert stmt

Tags: oracle, database-cursor

cursor's result is determined at the time of opened ? but the following demo reveal a difference :

```
drop table Highschooler;
drop table w;
create table Highschooler( grade int );
create table w( grade int );

insert into Highschooler(grade) values (13);
insert into Highschooler(grade) values(14);
insert into Highschooler(grade) values (15);
insert into w values (16);

select * from Highschooler;
select * from w;

create or replace create function ff(a int) return int is 
   total int := 0;
begin
  select  count(grade) into total from w where grade > a ;
  return total;
end;

DECLARE
   my_var int :=0;
   my_var2 int := 0;
   my_var3 int := 0;
   CURSOR CC IS select ff(grade) from Highschooler for update;
BEGIN
   open CC;
   fetch CC into my_var;
   insert into w values (16);
   fetch CC into my_var2;
   fetch CC into my_var3;
   dbms_output.put_line(my_var || '  - '  || my_var2 || ' - ' || my_var3);
   close CC;
end;
```

outputs:

```
GRADE
13
14
15
Download CSV
3 rows selected.

Result Set 4
GRADE
16
Statement processed. ------- the insert stmt in 'insert into w values (16);' affect the cursor's output here
1  - 2 - 2
```

Comment: Wouldn't you mind to boild down your example only to the relevant part, i.e. one table with one insert and cursor fetch and describe more in detail what *difference* you observed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function contains another cursor which is only opened at the time of execution. This is why you generally shouldn't use functions to just do SQL - you end up with logically corrupt data as each execution will be using a different SCN point.

Comment: the cursor execution completed when its open cursor returned ? if so, the function in the cursor also run to completed. if no the cursor will continue its execution after opened, until it was closed ? or the function only called at each of the result of cursor was fetched ? if this is the reason, why the cursor's result not the select stmt's resultset but the value before call the function ? thanks your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Define the cursor *without using a function*, such as

```
CURSOR CC IS 
select  (select  count(grade) from w where grade > h.grade) as ff 
from Highschooler h;
```

This will lead to the expected result

```
1  - 1 - 1
```

Note also that avoiding function use will lead to a better performance as you omit the *context switch*.

Comment: yes, what confuse me is the use of function affect the result when cursor was fecthing